# Restrict HashMap to accept a particular string key

Tags: java, hashmap

How can we restrict a HashMap to accept a particular string key.
Restriction here can have one of following meanings-
**1.** It can throw an error or 
**2.** It can simply ignore that entry which has that specific key.

But the condition is that it should be implemented without overriding `put` method of HashMap and without using `if` condition while adding an entry to given map.

Suppose I have a HashMap **m** and I want to restrict a particular string key **"myKey"**.
What I want is, whenever we try to add any entry with key "myKey", m should follow point 1 or point 2 as mentioned above.

```
m.put("otherKey", "value"); // should add to the map<br/>
m.put("myKey","value"); // Either throw an error or ignore this entry and should not add to the map.
```

I can restrict a type of keys using Genetics but how to do it for a single given string key. It was an interview question.
Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you cannot use a conditional?

Comment: It is an interview question...and the condition is to not use if

Answer (score 5):

You could use an emun as the key. Such as

```
public enum AllowedKey {
    KEY_ONE,
    KEY_TWO; // etc
}
```

Then use this in your Map:

```
Map<AllowedKey, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("string", "value"); // compile error!
map.put(AllowedKey.KEY_ONE, "value"); // success!
```

You could also use an EnumMap if your implementation allows this.

Edit: The definition of the HashMap cannot be changed, so this approach would no longer be applicable.

Answer (score 3):

These are very weird restrictions you have ... but here it is without an `if` statement or overriding:

```
void addToMap(HashMap<String,Sting> map, String key, String value) {
    switch (key) {
        case "MyKey":
             throw new IllegalArgumentException(key);
        default: map.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: it does what is asked and i guess you could do it the other way around as well i.e. `map.put(sanitizeString("myKey"),value);`, the `sanitizeString` could throw an exception.

Comment: It's not clear why OP needs to avoid `if`, but if they have a legitimate reason for doing so, they're presumably going to have the same problem with `switch`.  This example likely generates identical bytecode to an `if`.

Comment: Sure. The point is that there cannot be any "legitimate reason" to avoid an `if statement` (or to override `.put` for that matter). This question only makes any sense at all as a kind of riddle. Like "how do you swap two ints without using a temporary variable?"
@dimo414: the thing is that in your answer, the constructor for the `RestrictedString` would need an (equivalent of an) `if` statement anyway. And your first suggestion involves overriding `put` *and* an `if` statement, which are *both* prohibited :)

Comment: @Dima as you note, there has to be a conditional *somewhere*, so rather than proposing convoluted code, I discussed alternatives.  The OP objects to overriding `HashMap.put()`, not overriding in general (though that could certainly have been the intent).

Comment: The fact that `switch` *can* do the same thing as `if` is not a good reason to do so.  You could use any number of other control mechanisms to avoid literally typing `if`, but that's no reason to do so.

Comment: Of course not. There *is* no reason (or possibility) to avoid using a coditional, that's the whole point. If the question is to avoid `if` for whatever reason, this is the answer. If the question is to avoid `if` or any other equivalent control mechanism, then the answer is obviously "there is no way to do it".

Answer (score 2):

You could do any number of tricks to avoid explicitly typing `if`.  The existing answer using `switch` works, as would using a `while` loop and breaking or returning unconditionally inside of it.  If your interviewer really wants to see how you can write unpleasant code that's your answer.

If you're interested in *real* ways to restrict a `HashMap`'s keys, you should use Guava's [`ForwardingMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingMap.html) and extend *its* `.put*()` and `.putAll()` methods, throwing an [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) "[*if some property of the specified key or value prevents it from being stored in this map*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29)".  Even if you don't use Guava, you should prefer the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) over extending `HashMap` directly (*Effective Java: Item 16*).

Alternatively, you may find it easier to use a dedicated type for your keys, e.g. a `RestrictedString` class that does your sanitization.  Then you can create a `Map<RestrictedString, String>` and trust that only valid keys are in the map.  This avoids using a conditional (`if`/`switch`/etc.) in the `Map` code, instead moving it to the `RestrictedString` class.

Even if an interviewer is asking a puzzler-style question, responding with real-world solutions (while still acknowledging their stipulations) can only score you points with any legitimate employer.

Comment: i like the decorator pattern

Comment: "you should prefer the decorator pattern to extending HashMap directly."
Huh? Why?

Comment: @Dima The linked article discusses some of the benefits of the decorator pattern, but essentially it's [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), a standard best practice.

Comment: @dimo414  I would not call it "best practice". Inheritance is  hallmark feature of object-oriented design. Foregoing it in favor for another technique can't be "best practice". 
In this case, decorator pattern is just a workaround for lack of multiple inheritance in java. Pretty much, obsolete with java 8.

Comment: Let's agree to disagree, then.  But you're also disagreeing with [Effective Java #16](https://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81), and I wouldn't do so lightly.

Answer (score 1):

Use Set to store prohibited keys.

Then map true and false within a map:

```
Set prohibitedKeys = new HashSet<String>();
prohibitedKeys.add("myKey");
Map<Boolean,Map<String,String>> boolMap = new HashMap<Boolean,Map<String,String>>();
Map<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

boolMap.put(Boolean.FALSE,myMap);
//This will work
Map m = boolMap.get((Boolean)prohibitedKeys.contains("otherKey"))
m.put("otherKey", "value");

//This will throw an null pointer exception
m.put("myKey", "value");
```

Comment: This is ... inventive :) Love it!

Answer (score 0):

An EnumMap would allow the keys to be restricted to a static subset but would obviously break the requirement of `Map<String, String>`.

With a decorator, the decorator and the decorated class normally share an interface i.e. Map, so implementing a custom `put(k, v)` and passing all other methods through to the decorated HashMap may be acceptable as you are not directly overriding the `put(k, v)` method of HashMap.

The only other solution I can think of is using an AOP based solution to apply a 'before' advice to the put(k, v) method and which would reject any invalid values.